# Javascript detect default resolution of device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find out the device's default resolution. I want to detect that the browser is maximized as default or user is customized it. My code is to check if document width/height is equal to default width/height or not.

here is some -

```
screen.width
$(window).width()
window.innerWidth
window.outerWidth
```

But they are showing only for current document or window width, not the device's default width. How can I find that one with javascript or jQuery. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do because the CSS @media queries might be more efficient than using javascript

Answer (score 1):

We can get it using **Javascript** code

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
window.screen.width
window.screen.height
```

you can also get the pixel ratio by using:

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

Comment: unfortunately, if i change resolution, i can't calculate device's resolution anymore

Answer (score 0):

window.screen can solve your query. you can use properties like

window.screen.width

window.screen.height

```
{availWidth: 1920, availHeight: 1040, width: 1920, height: 1080, colorDepth: 24, …}
```